# dns setup for primary domain and subdomains

Tags: dns, subdomain, ip-address, cname, a-records

I would like to simplify my DNS entries as each time I add a subdomain, I currently have to go in and create a new A record.  So here is my scenario, I imagine it's fairly common:

My primary domain (let's say www.foo.com) points to one IP address (lets say XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX).

Subdomains (let's say demo.foo.com) point to another IP address, YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY.

How do I get www.foo.com and foo.com to continue to point to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, while any other subdomain ("wildcarded") points to YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY?  I'm guessing this is possible to do with CNAME, but I just want to make absolutely certain before I mess around with my production envrionment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to create a subdomain (node) called * and a CNAME record on there or an A-record. However, if you create a CNAME at that node, RFCs prevent any other record from being created at the wildcard node. I would recommend resolving to an A-record if you need that wildcard to have any sort of MX or TXT records in addition to the basic name resolution.

Some DNS providers are able to provide wildcard name resolution. DynECT Managed DNS Lite (http://dyn.com/dns/business/) provides this capability.